# Masking brain tumor with mrcnn

Tags: conv-neural-network, mask

I'm trying to recreate this one project on GitHub to mask a brain tumor using MRI scan. However I am running into a few problems here since the code that I adapt did not work quite well. Everything was going fine until I reach the "model.load_weights" part. It just showed that the NoneType object has no attribute "lower". So I wonder if you guys can tell me what is wrong here? I am trying to learn through Youtube videos so if I made any mistakes, please tell me nicely! Thanks a lot!!! Also, it would be great if you guys could give me some advices if you have already recreated this project before.

Here is the code that I adapt. I use MakeSense to create the annotations file.

```
import os
import sys 
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import skimage 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import matplotlib.patches 
from numpy import zeros, asarray 
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw import json 
import datetime import cv2

import mrcnn 
from mrcnn.visualize import display_instances 
from mrcnn.utils import extract_bboxes

from mrcnn.utils import Dataset
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

from mrcnn.config import Config 
from mrcnn.model import MaskRCNN

from mrcnn import model as modellib, utils
df= r"C:\Users\Brain MRI\mask\image_data"
train= os.path.join(df,'train') 
val=os.path.join(df,'val') 
pretrained_model=os.path.join(df,"mask_rcnn_coco.h5") 
log_dir=os.path.join(df,'logs') 
class Configuration(Config): 
  NAME = "coco" GPU_COUNT=1 IMAGES_PER_GPU=1  
  num_classes=1+1 
  STEPS_PER_EPOCH=45
  VALIDATION_STEPS=10
  IMAGE_MAX_DIM=256 
  IMAGE_MIN_DIM=256 
def init(self, num_classes):
  self.NUM_CLASSES = num_classes super().init()
  model_path=pretrained_model 
class BrainScanDataset(utils.Dataset):
def load_brain_scan(self, dataset_dir, subset):
    # Add classes. We have only one class to add.
    self.add_class(
        "tumor", 1, "tumor")

    # Train or validation dataset?
    assert subset in ["train", "val"]
    dataset_dir = os.path.join(df, subset)

    annotations = json.load(open(os.path.join(df, subset, 'annotations_'+subset+'.json')))
    annotations = list(annotations.values())  
    annotations = [a for a in annotations if a['regions']]
   

    # Add images
    for a in annotations:
        if type(a['regions']) is dict:
            polygons = [r['shape_attributes'] for r in a['regions'].values()]
        else:
            polygons = [r['shape_attributes'] for r in a['regions']]

        # load_mask() needs the image size to convert polygons to masks.
        # Unfortunately, VIA doesn't include it in JSON, so we must read
        # the image. This is only managable since the dataset is tiny.
        image_path = os.path.join(df,subset, a['filename'])
        image = skimage.io.imread(image_path)
        height, width = image.shape[:2]

        self.add_image("tumor",
            image_id=a['filename'],  # use file name as a unique image id
            path=image_path,
            width=width, 
            height=height,
            polygons=polygons
        )
def load_mask(self, image_id):
    # If not a farm_cow dataset image, delegate to parent class.
    image_info = self.image_info[image_id]
    if image_info["source"] != "tumor":
        return super(self.__class__, self).load_mask(image_id)
    info = self.image_info[image_id]
    mask = np.zeros([info["height"], info["width"], len(info["polygons"])],
                    dtype=np.uint8)
    for i, p in enumerate(info["polygons"]):
        # Get indexes of pixels inside the polygon and set them to 1
        rr, cc = skimage.draw.polygon(p['all_points_y'], p['all_points_x'])
        mask[rr, cc, i] = 1
def image_reference(self, image_id):
    info = self.image_info[image_id]
    if info["source"] == "tumor":
        return info["path"]
    else:
        super(self.__class__, self).image_reference(image_id)
dataset_train = BrainScanDataset() 
dataset_train.load_brain_scan(df, 'train') 
dataset_train.prepare()

dataset_val = BrainScanDataset() 
dataset_val.load_brain_scan(df, 'val') 
dataset_val.prepare()

model = modellib.MaskRCNN( mode='training', config=Config, model_dir=log_dir )

model.load_weights( pretrained_model, by_name=True, exclude=["mrcnn_class_logits", "mrcnn_bbox_fc", "mrcnn_bbox", "mrcnn_mask"] )
```

Answer (score 0):

error you are facing is maybe because of pre-trained model "mask_rcnn_coco.h5". check that this file correctly and also check is at correct path or not. also i suggest to check for

model.summary()
before model.load_weights(), it will help you to find model is correct or not.

or you can check that load_weights() is compatible with .h5 files or not.